# Finding 1953 Louisiana marriage license of parents?

Tags: marriage-records, louisiana, 1950s

My parents married in 1953. I think they went to Mississippi from Louisiana to marry. They didn’t want to do the waiting period. Then they came back the next day and were married by a priest in Avoyelles parish in Louisiana.

How can I find their marriage license?

Comment: Do you have the Avoyelles certificate/record?  That is the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You are a direct relative. Send requests to both the Mississippi and Louisiana Vital Records department on the appropriate forms and the required documentation, usually birth certificate. As a direct relative they will give you copies of their records, for a fee of course.